# Deleting store with products belong to it

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating a store and adding an item to store then trying to delete store and items belong to it.
it works perfect (if there is an item belong to store).
but if there isn't item belong to store, then it doesnt delete store.
stil shows store in database.
I am working on localhost

I will add total codes first if someone wants to try it.

> Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_GET['store_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['store_id'])){
$storeid = filterString($_GET['store_id']);

$bringa = bring_product_image($storeid);
foreach($bringa as $row);
$oldimage = "../images/items/".$row['item_image'];

$bring = bringstoreimage($storeid);
foreach($bring as $row);
$storeoldimage = "../images/stores/".$row['store_image'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE c,p FROM stores c
                        INNER JOIN products p ON c.store_id = p.storeid
                        WHERE store_id = :store_id
                        ');

$del = $stmt->execute(array(':store_id' =>$storeid));
if($del){
    unlink($storeoldimage);
    unlink($oldimage);
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Store deleted!";       
    header("location: success.php");
    exit(); 
}else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Something went wrong!";       
    header("location: error.php");
    exit(); 
}
```

}

> This is the part of code where I am having problem with.

```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE c,p FROM stores c
                            INNER JOIN products p ON c.store_id = p.storeid
                            WHERE store_id = :store_id
                            ');
```

Comment: Well, you can always delete the store first, then the products. Or try using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using left join.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE c,p FROM stores c
                        LEFT JOIN products p ON c.store_id = p.storeid
                        WHERE store_id = :store_id
                        ');
```

Comment: Iwas out couldn't answer, it works fine now thanks a lot.